# How do I not allow submission for empty fields from a child component? More explanation below

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this sample codesandbox I made, though, in my original one there were already a lot of values. I only recreated the problem that I had.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-firefly-40mig3?file=/src/App.js

I have this in my **`App.js`** where I define some of my needed values and then pass it to 2 other components.

```
  <div className="App">
      {/* some codes here */}
      <h1>App page</h1>
      Initial Amount: 1000
      <br />
      Total Amount: {totalAmount}
      <br />
      ----------------------------------------------------------
      <h6>Passing the total amount and the second input here</h6>
      <Second input2={input2} setInput2={setInput2} />
      ----------------------------------------------------------
      <h6>Third here</h6>
      <Third totalAmount={totalAmount} />
    </div>
```

I have this `Second.js` where I compute the `totalAmount`. This is the problem that I encountered. The `required` is not being recognized here. I just wanted to stop the user from submitting the form if this field is empty. Are there other ways where it would not submit if a certain field is empty or just leave the input field to 1 if it is empty?

```
const Second = ({ input2, setInput2 }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Second here
      <form>
        <input
          fullWidth
          value={input2}
          onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Second;
```

This is the **`Third.js`** where I passed down the `totalAmount` and added more values such as the `name` and `age`. In here the `name` and `age` are being recognized. This is also where I submit everything here.

```
const Third = ({ totalAmount }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log(name, age, totalAmount);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Third here
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          fullWidth
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <br /> <br />
        <label>Age</label>
        <input
          fullWidth
          value={age}
          onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <br /> <br />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Third;
```

Comment: All fields would have to live in the same `<form>`, not in two separate forms.

Comment: @FelixKling are there other ways where it would not submit if a certain field is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `input2` as a `prop` to **`Third.js`** and there you can check if `input2` doesn't exist then don't submit the values.

In the **`App.js`** pass `input2` to the `Third` component.

```
<Third totalAmount={totalAmount} input2={input2} />
```

Then in **`Third.js`** check if the `input2` value exists.

```
const Third = ({ totalAmount, input2 }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input2) {
      try {
        console.log(name, age, totalAmount);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }else {
      alert('Please enter the second value');        
    }
  }
}
```